# how do you sum tree in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
;; A [BT X] is one of 
;; - 'leaf
;; - (make-node X [BT X] [BT X])


(define-struct node (val left right))
;; interpretation: represents a node with a value
;; a left and right subtree

(define (tree-sum tree)
   (cond 
      [(symbol=? tree 'leaf) ...] ;; the value remains same 
      [(node? tree)
            (+ (tree-sum (node-val tree))
               (tree-sum (node-left tree))
               (tree-sum (node-right tree)))]))
```

not quite sure if i'm on the right track.

Normally, A pair tree is either

- a leaf (not a pair), or
- a pair, whose car and cdr values are pair-trees.

recursive summing procedure will have to deal with these two cases:

- a numbers, i.e., leaves of a tree of numbers, and
- pairs, in which case it should sum the left and right subtrees, and add those sums together.

Therefore,

```
(define (pair-tree-sum pair-tree)
    (cond 
       [(number? pair-tree)
             pair-tree]
       [else
             (+ (pair-tree-sum (car pair-tree))
                (pair-tree-sum (cdr pair-tree)))]))
```

Comment: Are you getting errors or unexpected output?

Comment: @Jack i'm still writing the codes. just thinking if it is better to do the summation in an accumulation style.

Comment: if the tree is simply a list of numbers, that will be much easier. However, it is a complex structure.

Comment: Are you asking about summing a `BT` tree, a tree represented as nested lists, or just asking whether you should use an accumulator?

Comment: @molbdnilo is there a way that we can turn all the numbers on the tree into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the function into two parts - one that converts the tree into a list of numbers, and another that just uses [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) with that list, and `foldl` has the advantage of automatically doing the summation as an accumulator.

```
(define (tree->list tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
      (append (tree->list (car tree))
              (tree->list (cdr tree)))
      (list tree)))

(define (tree-sum tree)
  (foldl + 0 (tree->list tree)))
```

Comment: I'm asked specifically not using foldl or any other loop functions to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: test: `(define tree
  (make-node 4 'leaf 
             (make-node 5 'leaf 'leaf)))`
error code: +: expects a number as 1st argument, given (make-node 4 'leaf (make-node 5 'leaf 'leaf))

Comment: This solution doesn't use a struct to represent the tree. A tree is either just a single number (a leaf), or a pair containing two trees. So `'(1 (2 . 3) . 4)` would be a tree. There's no structs or other data structures involved, just numbers and pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check if the tree is empty, then if its not a list, else you call the function sum to the car of the list, and add to the cdr of the list.

```
   (define (sum tree)
 (cond [(empty? tree) 0]
        [(not (list? tree)) (if (number? tree) tree 0)]
        [else (+ (sum (first tree)) (sum (rest tree)))]))
```